# Android wifi tethering (hotspot) DNS server (dnsmasq) returns 127.0.0.1 for some domains

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, cache, wifi-tethering, dns

My laptop connects to the internet through Android wifi tethering (hotspot).
Some websites cannot be connected because my Android DNS server returns `127.0.0.1`.
I **can** browse the sites **on my Android phone**, but **not through the hotspot** due to this strange DNS behavior.
For example, I can't connect to [tools.ietf.org](https://tools.ietf.org) to read RFC documentations. The DNS server just returns `127.0.0.1`.

Info about my Android device:
Redmi note 5 global/pro (whyred), running `MIUI 11`, `Android 9`.
The DNS server is `dnsmasq`, according to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226438/hotspot-mobile-network-tethering-and-dns), and I've checked it by `netstat`.
It is listening on `127.0.0.1:53` & `192.168.43.1:53`.

`sudo getprop | grep dns`:

```
[init.svc.mdnsd]: [running]
[net.dns1]: [172.24.x.x]  # this DNS server returns correct IP
[net.dns2]: [10.x.x.x]    # this returns 127.0.0.1 for some sites
[net.dns3]: [xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx]
[net.dns4]: [8.8.8.8]     # the always working 8.8.8.8
[ro.boottime.mdnsd]: [147300891920]
```

`dnsmasq` command found by `ps auxf`:

```
/system/bin/dnsmasq
  --keep-in-foreground     # Do NOT fork into the background, do NOT run in debug mode.
  --no-resolv              # Do NOT read resolv.conf.
  --dhcp-ignore-names      # Ignore hostnames provided by DHCP clients.
  --no-poll                # Do NOT poll /etc/resolv.conf file, reload only on SIGHUP.
  --dhcp-authoritative     # Assume we are the only DHCP server on the local network.
  --dhcp-option-force=43,ANDROID_METERED  # DHCP option sent even if the client does not request it.
  --pid-file               # Specify path of PID file (defaults to /var/run/dnsmasq.pid). Empty here.
  --listen-mark 0xf0063    # Socket mark to use for listen sockets.
  --user dns_tether        # Change to this user after startup. (defaults to nobody).
  --dhcp-range=192.168.42.2,192.168.42.254,1h
  --dhcp-range=192.168.43.2,192.168.43.254,1h
  ...
  --dhcp-range=192.168.51.2,192.168.51.254,1h
```

I killed the server launched by my system, and did some experiments.

If I add `--all-servers` (Always perform DNS queries to all servers.), `dig`'s response would be `ANSWER: 0`.
Because there's no server set. (Default conf file `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` not exists)

If I also add `--conf-file=/sdcard/dnsmasq.conf`, with file content `server=8.8.8.8`, I'm able to connect to [tools.ietf.org](https://tools.ietf.org).

Question is, what would `dnsmasq` do, when there's no config file (`dnsmasq.conf`)?
If there's no dns server specified, how does it query upstream DNS?
And why it works for most domains, but not all?
Guess there's something to do with `[net.dns2]: [10.x.x.x]    # this returns 127.0.0.1 for some sites`?

**Update 1** (more info)

After I reboot my phone, the [10.x.x.x] DNS server returns `ANSWER: 0`.
My `dnsmasq` returns correct answer. I don't know why.

I read & searched more to understand Android DNS more.
Here's more info:

`sudo /system/bin/dumpsys netd`:

```
  NetworkController
    Default network: 100

    Networks:
      1 PHYSICAL rmnet_data0
        Required permission: SYSTEM
        No DNS servers defined
        No search domains defined
        Private DNS mode: OFF
        No Private DNS servers configured

      2 PHYSICAL
        ...

      51 DUMMY dummy0
        ...

      99 LOCAL wlan0
        ...

      100 PHYSICAL rmnet_data1
        Required permission: NONE
        DNS servers: # IP (total, successes, errors, timeouts, internal errors, RTT avg, last sample)
          172.24.x.x (64, 64, 0, 0, 0, 61ms, 54s)
          10.x.x.x <no data>
        No search domains defined
        DNS parameters: sample validity = 1800s, success threshold = 25%, samples (min, max) = (8, 64)
        Private DNS mode: OFF
        No Private DNS servers configured


    Interface <-> last network map:
      Ifindex: 10 NetId: 100
      Ifindex: 9 NetId: 1

    Interface addresses:
      address: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 ifindices: [26]
      address: 192.168.43.1/24 ifindices: [26]
      address: x.x.x.x/30 ifindices: [10]
      address: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 ifindices: [9]

  Dns Resolve Records
  total records=1000
    rec[0]: 13:58:37 3961 10032  s*.com=127.*,
    ...
    rec[999]: 19:50:04 3961 10032  s*.com=127.*,

  TrafficController
    BPF module status: OFF
```

So there are 2 DNS servers in `rmnet_data1`.
I think these are upstream servers dnsmasq would query.
Maybe it queryed the 10.x.x.x DNS server, which returned `127.0.0.1`, then it cached this wrong result.
A reboot may have cleared this, or it is out of life time now.

I just found there's a `--log-queries  Log DNS queries.` option in dnsmasq.
So I would be able to see what exactly happens the next time I fail to connect to tools.ietf.org.

So it seems to be my upstream DNS servers' problem, with some probability of happening because there are 2 DNS servers?
So this is my ISP's problem? Not resolving some domains correctly?

Some very nice Q&A here:

- [DNS queries are cached permanently, how to reliably clear DNS cache on Android 7+?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220054/dns-queries-are-cached-permanently-how-to-reliably-clear-dns-cache-on-android-7): explains DNS query in details
- [How does Android OS do DNS name resolution?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218015/how-does-android-os-do-dns-name-resolution/218209#218209): explains Android DNS resolv in details

**Update 2** (guessing reason / answer)

I think this strange behavior (able to connect on phone, but not through hotspot) is because there are 2 DNS cache in Android, one in system & another in Java. (According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59066207))

Chrome & other apps are probably using Java cache. The `dnsmasq` native binary is using system cache. I guess this is why.

In the end, though already dug quite deeply, I still didn't find a good way to solve this.
Next time I encounter this problem, I'll still just change my laptop's DNS server to `8.8.8.8`.